# analysis of variance - independence of samples and independence of individuals

Tags: anova, variance, sampling, independence, psychology

I am a bit confused with the concept of "independence of samples" in Analysis of Variance methods. One condition for performing an ANOVA is apparently "independence of the samples".

Most of my analysis are not performed on experimental randomised data but on large national representative surveys (ISSP, WVS, EVS, ...). The observations in these surveys have been randomly sampled (as best as possible) and are independent from each other.
For example, one analysis would be to compare `mean time spent in sleeping by different levels of education` using ANOVA.

What does "independence of the samples" means in this context ? Are my different *levels of education* for example "independent samples" ? How should I understand "independence of the samples" in a non-experimental, but still random, sampling ?

What kind of analysis of variance would be appropriate for these kind of large representative surveys ?

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like the independent/dependent versions of the t-test. Independent samples ANOVA means that none of the participants/cases are in more than one of the groups you are comparing. When you have dependent samples (when a case is in multiple groups) you need to use a repeated measures ANOVA.

This is not connected to whether or not your data were collected using random sampling. That characteristic indicates the quality and generalizability of the sample -- not whether you can use a certain type of ANOVA.

BTW - Do not confuse "random sampling" with "random assignment" to intervention/control groups -- a requirement for an experimental study.